# Plot function y = tan(yx)

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Could you help me to understand this expression y = tan(yx)?
Desmos.com renders it like image below:

[image: y=tan(xy)]

I am trying to write a function to do similar in JavaScript.
To do so, I have to rearrange it in this way:

y = tan(xy)
tan-1(y) = xy
x = tan-1(y)/y

But, this expression only draws the middle line?
What am I doing wrong?

Need to understand how to rearrange y=tan(xy) expression to get something similar to the first illustration with JavaScript or any other programming language.

[image: x=tan-1(y)/y]

Comment: y = tan (y x) is not a function; it is, however, an equation in the coordinates in the plane.

Comment: That's why I called it 'expression' and tried to rearrange everything to x=tan-1(y)/y

Basically, my question is how to build a function out of it to be able to draw graph similar to first visual reference.

Comment: NB: there's also the $y=0$ case you have to take care of. $(x,0)$ is a solution for all $x$ (that's the orange horizontal line in the first plot)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Davids answer, we consider standard $\tan^{-1}(x)$ function $\Bbb R \to (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. From the equation $y = \tan(yx)$ you can very well say

$$\tan^{-1}(y) = \tan^{-1}(\tan(yx))$$

Now we cannot simplify right side to simply $yx$! Now since the range of $\tan^{-1}()$ is $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $\tan^{-1}(\tan(yx)) = yx$ if and only $yx \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

For other values of $yx$, say if $yx \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2})$ then $yx - \pi \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Thus for this we get $$\tan^{-1}(\tan(yx))= \tan^{-1}(\tan(yx-\pi)) = yx - \pi$$

Similarly say $yx \in (-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2})$ then $yx+\pi \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and so $$\tan^{-1}(\tan(yx))= \tan^{-1}(-\tan(yx+\pi)) = -yx - \pi$$

Answer (score 9):

The function $\tan^{-1}$ always gives an answer between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$.  The complete solution of $b=\tan a$ is
$$x=\tan^{-1}b+k\pi\ ,\quad\hbox{$k$ is an integer.}$$
So in your case,
$$xy=\tan^{-1}y+k\pi\ .$$
You have implicitly assumed that $k$ has one specific value ($k=0$), which is why you have only got one curve instead of many.

Comment: And what about y = 1 / cos(xy)
While acos has range from 0 to π, instead of −π/2 and π/2
what should put instead of kπ?

1 / y = cos(xy)
arcos(1/y) = xy
x = arcos(1/y) / y or -arcos(1/y) / y

Comment: The solution of $b=\cos a$ is $a=\pm\cos^{-1}b+2k\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.